# Treemap and List View

Tags: java, android

Hy!

I have a Treemap  and i want to set all strings in the map to the ListView

Code:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> map = json.getChannels(lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
ListView lv2 = new ListView(Channellist.this);
Set st = map.keySet();
lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Channellist.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,st));
```

My Problem is that the ArrayAdapter doesn't support a Set.

Are there any Solutions?

THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an ArrayList and all all the elements from the set. Pass this list.

```
ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(st);
```

Now use `l`. Or just create an Array:

```
String[] array = (String[])set.toArray(new String[st.size()]);
```

EDIT: Added enhancement from comment.

EDIT2: Add @SupressWarnings("unchecked") to your function. I have to do this all the time when using external APIs that use pre-1.5 ungeneric code :).

Comment: Even better - `ArrayList l = new ArrayList(st)`, which automatically adds all the elements.

Comment: is there an alternative to set, because eclipse drops warnings?